# jquery and vimeo: won't autoplay

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I have a vimeo video that loads when the user clicks on a div.

```
<div class="vimeobox" ID="vimeo-ID-goes-here"></div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(".vimeobox").click(function() {

        var iframe = "<iframe />";
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); // 
        var url = "http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + id + "?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1";

        var width = 700;
        var height = 394;
        var frameborder = 0;

         $(iframe, {
            name: 'videoframe',
            id: 'videoframe',
            src: url,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            frameborder: frameborder,
            type: 'text/html',
            allowfullscreen: true,
            webkitAllowFullScreen: true,
            mozallowfullscreen: true
        }).css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0', 'left': '0'}).appendTo(this);

        $(this).find('img').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove();

        });

    });
```

The vimeo player appears when the div is clicked on (removing the preview image)...but the video does not autoplay.

I don't know what the issue is. I am using near-identical code for a youtube player (minus the url variable) and it autoplays?

Comment: That totally worked! I wonder why the link is presented that way in the vimeo embed code then?

Comment: I don't know, usually this is the `?` that is used as separator so you don't have to escape the ampersand (but there are a lot of valid characters that you can use as separator as long as the HTTP server support them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `&amp;` in your url by `?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this manually by adding the following parameters into your embed code:
loop=1
autoplay=1
If you have more than one video autoplaying on a particular page, you will also need to include this parameter:
autopause=0

Comment: I was missing autopause=0, after adding autopause=0 multiple videos are working perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are indeed correct BUT if your experiencing problems getting autoplay to function on mobile devices your out of luck as default AutoPlay functionality as described here will NOT WORK on mobile devices (Android/iOS and probably Windows Mobile) as of the time of this writing.

If anyone has figured out a hack to force autoplay to function please post.